# How to use Common.Logging.Log4Net.Universal instead of Common.Logging.Log4Net208

Tags: log4net

I have a solution that I cannot update to Log4Net 2.0.12 because the `Common.Logging.Log4Net208` has not been updated and the project seems pretty well dead.

While searching the nuget package, I saw `Common.Logging.Log4Net.Universal`

I added it (and removed the Common.Logging.Log4Net208) but there was a config section like-a-so:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="common">
        <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />        
</configSections>

...

<common>
    <logging>
        <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net208">
            <arg key="configType" value="FILE-WATCH" />
            <arg key="configFile" value="~/log4net.config" />
        </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
</common>
```

I was not able to find any example as to how to set this up with `Common.Logging.Log4Net.Universal` as attempting with the same section produced an error while compiling as `Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter` was no longer found. And removing the complete section(s) caused error at runtime when logging.

Anyone has experience with `Common.Logging.Log4Net.Universal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out by going through examples:

```
<common>
    <logging>
        <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Universal.Log4NetFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net.Universal">
            <arg key="configType" value="FILE-WATCH"/>
            <arg key="configFile" value="~/log4net.config" />
        </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
</common>
```